# D3.js Highlight an element when hovering over another

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hover

I have a donut chart made using D3.js. I would like to change the color of the arc when hovering over the corresponding text.

I know how to change the color of the first, or all, but the corresponding one.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ydx9y9sx/)'s the code so far. The lines that do the highlighting are the following:

```
           .on("mouseover", function(d,i){
              //d3.select(".donutArcSlices").transition().style("fill", "#007DBC");
              //d3.selectAll(".donutArcSlices").transition().style("fill", "#007DBC");
              div.transition()      
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(d.name)   
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
              d3.select(".donutArcSlices").transition().style("fill", "#3E4750");
              div.transition()      
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
            });
```

If I add the first commented line, when I hover over any of the texts in the arcs, the first arc changes colors. If I remove the comments on the second line, then all of the arcs change colors upon hovering over any of the texts.

Comment: Both answers work well, I will let the community decide which one should be accepted as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Give each path an unique ID:

```
.attr("id", function(d,i){ return "donut"+i})
```

And use it when hovering:

```
d3.select("#donut" + i).transition().style("fill", "#007DBC");
```

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d6839s03/

PS: your `mouseout` function is making everything gray.

Comment: Yeah, `mouseout` was not completely implemented as it uses the same feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the correct path like this :

```
d3.selectAll(".donutArcSlices").filter(function(e, j){ return i === j}).style("fill", "#007DBC");
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/o98b8fsj/

Answer (score 1):

Awesome answer for Gerardo. Anyone trying it with D3js v5 can use the same underlying concept.
I am using D3js V5 + Angular 6 with the following code snippets-

1. add id attribute to the node or any other element you want to manipulate -

   `this.svg.append('g').attr('id' ,(d,i)=>'elementname'+i)`
2. then just make the changes on the d3js event of your choice -

   `.on('mousehover', (d,i)=> d3.select('#elementname'+i).style('fill','red')
    .on('mouseout', (d,i)=> d3.select('#elementname'+i).style('fill','black')`